# How to resynchronise git repos

Tags: git

I have a bare git repo that I push to from the development host and pull from the deployment host.  The routine on the development host is git checkout master, pull, do work, commit, push.  Then on the deployment host the routine is checkout master, pull.

Today I have run into a strange situation.

This is what the bare origin repo says:

```
[root@pas-redmine hll_powerhouse.git (BARE:master)]# git log
commit 53f2da6924ba0f7d55292084179a25042b46084b (HEAD -> master)
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 15:10:49 2020 -0400

    refs #1646 - QZCCLED - Remove duplicate lines - comment out count and subhdr

commit a9de26775c31c096479ff3f7e70fb5b5fc662f38
Merge: a22895e 169cedb
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 14:29:32 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'master' of ssh://vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse

commit 169cedbb65cdf3fda0a00cb7faac3a50b6d5390b
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 14:22:35 2020 -0400

    refs #1646 - QZCCLED - Remove duplicate lines

commit a22895e679b45741afb9c3e8276a8fe7d245bf51
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Fri Aug 28 14:08:52 2020 -0400

    refs #1624 - QZCCMWR - Update LVS cutoff to 3300.00
```

This is what the deployment host says:

```
[root@bkuprcvy powerhouse]$ git log
commit 53f2da6924ba0f7d55292084179a25042b46084b (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 15:10:49 2020 -0400

    refs #1646 - QZCCLED - Remove duplicate lines - comment out count and subhdr

commit a9de26775c31c096479ff3f7e70fb5b5fc662f38
Merge: a22895e 169cedb
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 14:29:32 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'master' of ssh://vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse

commit 169cedbb65cdf3fda0a00cb7faac3a50b6d5390b
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 14:22:35 2020 -0400

    refs #1646 - QZCCLED - Remove duplicate lines

commit a22895e679b45741afb9c3e8276a8fe7d245bf51
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Fri Aug 28 14:08:52 2020 -0400

    refs #1624 - QZCCMWR - Update LVS cutoff to 3300.00

[root@bkuprcvy powerhouse]$ git pull
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
    byrnejb_hll@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca's password: 
    Already up to date.
    [root@bkuprcvy powerhouse]$ git push
    !!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                    legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                    (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
    byrnejb_hll@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca's password: 
    Everything up-to-date
```

And this is what the development host says:

```
[byrnejb_hll@vhost01 powerhouse (master)]$ git log
commit d4035ac4048f1c1006ddd2a49f855ac6162132ce (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Mon Nov 30 14:42:05 2020 -0500

    refs 1660 -QZARLIR - use LEGAL-NAME in place of DESCRIPTION on invoices

commit a22895e679b45741afb9c3e8276a8fe7d245bf51
Author: James B. Byrne <byrnejb@harte-lyne.ca>
Date:   Fri Aug 28 14:08:52 2020 -0400

    refs #1624 - QZCCMWR - Update LVS cutoff to 3300.00

[byrnejb_hll@vhost01 powerhouse (master)]$ git pull
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
Already up to date.
[byrnejb_hll@vhost01 powerhouse (master)]$ git push
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
Everything up-to-date
```

Now, commit d4035ac404 is not in the origin, although git on devel seems to believe that nothing is missing.  Likewise commits 53f2da6924, 169cedbb65, and 169cedbb65 are missing from devel but devel does not seem to mind this either. Master and deploy seem to be in sync.  So what happened to commit d4035ac404 and why does devel not wish to merge 53f2da6924, 169cedbb65, and 169cedbb65?

More to the point.  How is this fixed?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to run ```gitk``` and add an image of the graph?

Comment: The commit hash IDs are the important things, and as you noted, they don't match on these various machines. Make sure the Git your development host is reaching, when you use `git <syncwith> origin`, is the host you think it is (though why that might have *changed* is also a mystery). The various `HEAD -> master` outputs indicate that the current branch name in each repository is `master`, so unless you have a nonstandard upstream and push setting, everything should be working, and it's clearly not.

Comment: this is what each system has configured it its copy of the repo:

Comment: from devel

    [remote "origin"]
     url = ssh://name@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: url = ssh://name@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse.git

Comment: from deploy

[remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 url = ssh://name@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse.git

Comment: url = ssh://name@vcs-git.internal.harte-lyne.ca/var/db/git/hll_powerhouse.git`

Comment: I discovered this solution to resting the local repo, at the cost of losing all local commits not on the remote.
#
# git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && git clean -f -d